# Error CRS-5014 when runing RAC 11gr2 on Redhat 6

Tags: listener, rac, oracle-grid-control

My database using RAC 11gr2 with two node on Redhat 6.

My system running fine, but after some time about 3-4 days. Process "ora.LISTENER.lsnr"  change status Online to INTERMEDIATE and then pedding, can not connect any session.

I reboot server it fine :) (restart instance or listener is not working)

This error exists only node2.

This is log of error in */u01/11.2.0/grid/log/node2/agent/crsd/oraagent_grid/oraagent_grid.log* file:

```
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] Agent::abort last call info:  "Agent::Agent refreshAttr"
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] abort command: check
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] tryActionLock {
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][134007104]{1:32952:11577} [check] (:CLSN00009:)Utils:execCmd abort request: killing /u01/11.2.0/grid/bin/lsnrctl
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][134007104]{1:32952:11577} [check] clsnUtils::error Exception type=2 string=
CRS-5014: Agent "/u01/11.2.0/grid/bin/oraagent.bin" timed out starting process "/u01/11.2.0/grid/bin/lsnrctl" for action "check": details at "(:CLSN00009:)" in "/u01/11.2.0/grid/log/node2/agent/crsd/oraagent_grid/oraagent_grid.log"

2017-06-17 09:23:28.859: [ora.LISTENER.lsnr][134007104]{1:32952:11577} [check] clsnUtils::error Exception type=2 string=
CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.LISTENER.lsnr check" encountered the following error: 
(:CLSN00009:)Utils:execCmd aborted. For details refer to "(:CLSN00109:)" in "/u01/11.2.0/grid/log/node2/agent/crsd/oraagent_grid/oraagent_grid.log".

[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] got lock
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] tryActionLock }
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] abort  }
[ora.LISTENER.lsnr][239827264]{1:32952:11577} [check] (:CLSN00110:) clsn_agent::abort }
[    AGFW][239827264]{1:32952:11577} Command: check for resource: ora.LISTENER.lsnr node2 1 completed with status: TIMEDOUT
[    AGFW][209729856]{1:32952:11577} ora.LISTENER.lsnr node2 1 state changed from: ONLINE to: UNKNOWN
[    AGFW][209729856]{1:32952:11577} ora.LISTENER.lsnr node2 1 would be continued to monitored!
[    AGFW][209729856]{1:32952:11577} ora.LISTENER.lsnr node2 1 state details has changed from:  to: CHECK TIMED OUT
[    AGFW][209729856]{0:1:4} Generating new Tint for unplanned state change. Original Tint: {1:32952:11577}
[    AGFW][209729856]{0:1:4} Agent sending message to PE: RESOURCE_STATUS[Proxy] ID 20481:134789
[ora.asm][239827264]{2:50449:2} [check] CrsCmd::ClscrsCmdData::stat entity 1 statflag 33 useFilter 0
```

How to fix this error. Thanks.